# Would screens on my attic vents prevent the recurrence of termites?

Tags: termite

5 years ago I had a termite company use Termidor and than Borate in our attic.  With a new inspection they have found a few swarmers, but no evidence of additional damage.  Would adding screens to the vents be a good idea?  They also recommend to re-apply the Borate. Would that be a waste? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Screens might reduce the total incidence of insects in your attic, but no attic is completely sealed. They will get in eventually.

Yes, reapplying insecticide will kill insects again. Whether that's a waste is a matter of opinion. Without knowing anything about your climate, home, stance on the use of pesticides, etc. I don't have one to share.

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention what type of Termite or your location.

1: Termites can slip through a crack in the concrete 1/32 of an inch wide. That is really small - how small is your netting? Is it cloth  - then it is a waste of money as the netting is probably not small enough gaps.

The termites are in your attic or are they carpenter ants ?
Termites prefer the darkness. I suspect misdiagnosed and they are carpenter ants.

I would wonder where the termites are coming from to get into the attic in the first place. That is a question I would really be looking at. They are not picking out your house and saying that one.

I would suspect a subterranean colony somewhere or a *misdiagnoses of carpenter ant* versus termite. Termites like moisture and darkness.

Your screens would be ineffective - treating the wood and the attic with things that kill both carpenter ants and termites is a good solution - treating around your house for termites also a good idea.

One thing to look for is on any baseboard, wall board is like cracking or dull orange peel like paint or tiny dirt holes like a pin hole. This tells you termites are there. Sometimes you might see them like small fly maggots or larvae in the wall board.

Press against base boards and things like that and see if anything is soft.